# MotionLayout using Crossfade - altSrc appears on top of src (original image doesn't fade away)

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

I am using an ImageFilterView, in coordination with a MotionScene, to switch between Images on user swipe (I am also moving the image up).

The new image does appear, but the old image remains. I can see the *altSrc* image on top of the original image.

[image: LogoWithOldAndNew]

Am I doing something wrong?  **Is my expectation incorrect that, the old image will fade out?**

Here is the relevant code:

**layout.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/motionlayout_demo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/the_scene_alt"
    app:showPaths="true"
    tools:context="com.designdemo.uaha.ui.MotionLayoutActivity">

...

    <androidx.constraintlayout.utils.widget.ImageFilterView
        android:id="@+id/nerd_text_img"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_nerderytxt_old"
        app:altSrc="@drawable/ic_nerderytxt_new"
        android:layout_width="450dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.43"/>

...

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

**the_scene_alt.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
        motion:duration="1000">
        <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@id/text_the"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="right" />
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/nerd_text_img"
            android:layout_width="450dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.43" >
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="Crossfade"
                motion:customFloatValue="0" />
        </Constraint>        
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">   
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/nerd_text_img"
            android:layout_width="450dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.33" >
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="Crossfade"
                motion:customFloatValue="1" />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>
```

Comment: As I have learned, this is probably working as expected.  The Crossfade puts the image on top, without changing the base layer.  Hoping I can get official confirmation.

Comment: Boo! Hope we can get this changed, for now ill just put the background into the image, not very nice but it will work for my purposes.

Comment: Yeah, they added a fix for this!  Author of lib added an answer!

Answer (score 6):

Use the flag:
 app:overlay="false"

Comment: Looks like this answer was recently added (by the author of CL), so I am going to assume this is a new addition to the library.

Comment: This is not that obvious when thinking of why the ImageFilterView exists in the first place. I'd say the most common use case is to crossfade which should be the default behaviour. Maybe I need to create a ticket to Google to change the behaviour or add support for this in Android Studio 4.0 motion editor.